# Conquering CSS, algorithmically

Tags: css, stylesheet

Before delving into my question, I should first provide a synopsis of what angle I'm coming from:  for most of my web development work (up until about a year ago), I have focused almost entirely on back-end development.  Hence, much of my recent months have been spent coming up to speed on JavaScript, AJAX tools, JS libraries, DOM Manipulation, and of course: Cascading Style Sheets.  I have found a way to adapt and leverage my mode of thinking to just about all of these aspects of web-development and do some truly neat things ***but*** CSS continues to be elusive to me.  Just about every web resource I've encountered that explains how to use CSS, describes this technology in a very piece-meal fashion.  So far I see nothing more than and endless list of example layouts and styles that make them happen.  And of course, to make matters worse: there's often multiple ways to achieve the same end, and a myriad of fragmented "gotchas" to deal with browser inconsistencies.

To me: CSS is *not* a fully-functional programming language (i.e. it is *not* Turing complete).  Hence, learning CSS is like trying to hack a complex XML file without having a clear idea how the software consuming said file will interpret it.  **What I am looking for is an algorithmic description of *exactly* how CSS is interpreted by each of the major browsers (IE, Chrome and FireFox).**  To me, this would be far more preferable than the brute-force approach I've been forced to use so far.

Comment: thanks mVChr, good call on the formatting change :-)

Comment: `What I am looking for is an algorithmic description of exactly how CSS is interpreted by each of the major browsers (IE, Chrome and FireFox)` - I don't think this exists (at least not all in one place), especially if you're considering older versions of IE. There's the way it *should be*, which you can find out by reading the relevant W3 specs. And then there's the way it *actually is*, with all the nasty quirks/inconsistencies/variations of behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS is indeed a different beast. As you suggested, [it is not Turing complete](http://frankmccabe.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/sub-turing-complete-programming-languages/). Furthermore, understanding a Turing complete language will not help you very much with understanding CSS. A CSS rule that you write may or may not be applied by the browser depending on many factors:

- "Weight"
- Location
- Importance
- Scope
- Inheritance

You almost have to get into the browser's head to write CSS :). But, these resources should help you:

**Straight from the source:** http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

**Article:** http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

---

## Edit

If you'd like to check out some of the actual code that performs these calculations (example being Firefox), then look through these files at the link below. Included, also, are the default CSS rule sets that Firefox applies automatically to every page.

- https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/078a4bcba8c5/layout/style

Comment: But are these *algorithmically* complete in their descriptions?  How about differences in the algorithms that each browser uses?  Pardon me if this seems a bit stubborn but I am essentially looking for some *code* ... pseudo-code would probably be adequate.

Comment: Browsers apply the same general algorithm, but with quirks. Generally, the quirks come from (a) their default style sheets, (b) whether the CSS engine (the part the calculates which rules to apply) understands each rule (some browsers support their own unique rules, after all), and (c) if the layout engine (the part that actually displays text, images, etc.) accurately handles the elements it needs to display. All of these things are well beyond the scope of the question you asked, but I'd invite you to look at the source code of say, Mozilla Firefox. Hope this helps.

Comment: **You almost have to get into the browser's head to write CSS **     And since "the browser's head" is a well-defined algorithm, that is exactly why I am looking for an algorithm :-)  At any rate, you make some very useful points, and I will definitely do some more reading.  In fact, I might even just RTFS (hint: S = Source).  FireFox and WebKit are open-source so ...

Comment: I know you are looking for an algorithm, but know this: The simplest explanation you will get is from the first two links I posted. If you want anything else more in depth, you will need to read the actual source code. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try reading [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/). I'd suggest reading at least the 'Box model' and 'Visual formatting model' sections. If you understand the core concepts there, the rest is details!

Answer (score 1):

This is the official CSS homepage: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/

Here's the full specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/

They should provide the background you're looking for.  However, languages like CSS are often best learnt through examples.  There are so many inconsistencies between browsers that the best thing to do is just gain experience.  You'll soon learn the ins and outs and the differences will become apparent over time.